# "Cannot resolve parameter" error in ABP Framework Test

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nsubstitute, abp

I am trying to write test code:

```
public class SupplierAppServiceTests : ABCApplicationTestBase
{
    private readonly ISupplierAppService _supplierAppService;
    private readonly IWmsCompanyRepository _fakeRepo;

    public SupplierAppServiceTests()
    {
        _fakeRepo = Substitute.For<IWmsCompanyRepository>();
        _supplierAppService = GetRequiredService<ISupplierAppService>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_Be_Generate_Code()
    {
        // Arrange
        _fakeRepo.CreateAsync(Arg.Any<WmsCompany>())
            .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
        ...
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while activating MyCompany.ABC.Application.CompanySuppliers.SupplierAppService.
    ---- Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyCompany.ABC.Application.CompanySuppliers.SupplierAppService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
    Cannot resolve parameter 'MyCompany.ABC.Domain.Wms.Companies.IWmsCompanyRepository wmsCompanyRepository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyCompany.ABC.Domain.Companies.SupplierManager, MyCompany.ABC.Domain.Companies.ISupplierRepository, MyCompany.ABC.Domain.Wms.Companies.IWmsCompanyRepository)'.
```

`WmsCompanyRepository` class (last parameter) which implements `IWmsCompanyRepository` makes a request to 3rd party's webservice.

`SupplierAppService`:

```
public class SupplierAppService : ABCAppService, ISupplierAppService
{
    public SupplierAppService(SupplierManager supplierManager, ISupplierRepository supplierRepository, IWmsCompanyRepository wmsCompanyRepository)
    {
        this.supplierManager = supplierManager;
        this.supplierRepository = supplierRepository;
        this.WmsCompanyRepository = wmsCompanyRepository;
    }

    ...
}
```

`IWmsCompanyRepository`:

```
public interface IWmsCompanyRepository
{
     Task CreateAsync(WmsCompany company);
}
```

I changed `_supplierAppService` assignment in `SupplierAppServiceTests` class' constructor

from:

```
_supplierAppService = GetRequiredService<ISupplierAppService>();
```

to:

```
_supplierAppService = new SupplierAppService(_supplierManager, _supplierRepository, _fakeRepo);
```

`SupplierAppService`'s methods use `ObjectMapper` property and this time I am getting this error:

```
ObjectMapper -> System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider') objectmapper
```

How can I inject `IWmsCompanyRepository` to `SupplierAppService` properly for test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your `_fakeRepo` singleton to `services` so that it can be resolved for `SupplierAppService`.

```cs
public SupplierAppServiceTests()
{
    // _fakeRepo = Substitute.For<IWmsCompanyRepository>();
    _supplierAppService = GetRequiredService<ISupplierAppService>();
}

protected override void AfterAddApplication(IServiceCollection services)
{
    _fakeRepo = Substitute.For<IWmsCompanyRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton(_fakeRepo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround,
I changed SupplierAppService class:

- Add default value `IWmsCompanyRepository wmsCompanyRepository = null` to ctor parameter
- Change WmsCompanyRepository from field to public property
- Add WmsCompanyRepository property to ISupplierAppService

---

```
public class SupplierAppService : ABCAppService , ISupplierAppService
{
   public IWmsCompanyRepository WmsCompanyRepository { get; set; }
   public SupplierAppService(SupplierManager supplierManager, ISupplierRepository supplierRepository,IWmsCompanyRepository wmsCompanyRepository = null)
   {
      this.supplierManager = supplierManager;
      this.supplierRepository = supplierRepository;
      this.WmsCompanyRepository = wmsCompanyRepository;
   }
 ...
 }
```

and changed SupplierAppServiceTests ctor:

```
public SupplierAppServiceTests()
{
    _fakeRepo = Substitute.For<IWmsCompanyRepository>();
    _supplierAppService = GetRequiredService<ISupplierAppService>();
    _supplierAppService.WmsCompanyRepository = _fakeRepo;
}
```